# How to compare two functions in PHP?

Tags: php

What would be the best way to check if two functions (not the output, as this might return false positives) are identical? A simple check does not do the trick.

The code below is an abstract example, real world use case might be comparing provided closures in a function to prevent doing the same thing twice.

```php
$function1 = function ($one, $two) {
    return $one + $two;
};

$function2 = function ($one, $two) {
    return $one + $two;
};

$same = ($function1 == $function2); // false
```

Comment: I wouldn't assign functions to variables in PHP..

Comment: and what's your actual problem here? Why would there ever be the worry that you coded something twice?

Comment: Hi, thanks for having a look! Use case: functions that are provided via a closure. I've updated my question to reflect my goal better.

Comment: Get code of functions via ReflectionAPI and compare it somehow.

Comment: @BertH So you want to check equality of code inside it?

Comment: question: what exactly are you trying to _achieve_ in the end and why?

Comment: @vivek_23: yeah, that's correct.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: A repo takes in closures with needed joins from other services. (e.g. to prepare data for later filtering). When two services need the same join, this check should duplicates. Not the everyday use case, I know :)